# Numbers inside a pandas dataframe have changed

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, column-types

I am a beginning programmer and currently working in Dataiku on a dataset with around 27000 records. The original/parent dataset has telephone numbers stored inside a string element, for example '0612345678' and '0229123456'.

However, when I load this dataset into my python script the datatype AND the numbers inside the columns changed. The column is now a float64 object and the telephone numbers from the example look as follows: '612345678.0' and '229123456.0'.

I tried to change the column data type using `df['telephone_number'].astype(str)` and the data type did change. However, the numbers are still showed in the wrong way ('612345678.0'). Can anyone please help me to change the numbers back to their original shape so that I can use them for my future analysis?

Comment: Possibly its due to the presence of `NaN` inside your `telephone_number` columns.....you can use `df['telephone_number'].astype(int)` if it shows you an `error` that means you have `NaN values inside your `'telephone_number' columns...Then you have to fill or drop them according to your need after that use `df['telephone_number'].astype(int)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Thanks a lot! This was the problem and I now solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which type you want to read a specific column as.

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", dtype={'TelephoneNum': str})
```